# finding out why a webapp is slow when hosted

Tags: django, host, performance

I have a `django web app` that uses `postgres` db.It allows users to login and make some posts which get saved to db and later on the user can list how many posts he made on a particular day etc and list the posts belonging to a particular category etc.While this worked without any delay in my machine,it is taking a lot of time to load each page when hosted on a `free` host.

How do you find out why this is happening?which part of the app should I look first?Is there any meaning in using a profiler since this app used to run with no delays in my local machine?

I would like to find out how to approach this problem in general.I was able to access other apps hosted on the same free host without much delays ..so this may be a problem specific to my app

I would like some advice regarding this..If anyone can help..

thank you
p.s:(I intentionally left out the host's name because ,since that was a free service ,there was no point in complaining and also other apps on the same host works well)

Comment: With free hosts, you get what you pay for, IMO.

Comment: Have you tried Django Debug Toolbar?http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar.  It will tell you the speeds of all your queries.  Might be a good place to start.

Comment: I agree with rockingskier that queries are indeed a good place to start. Sometimes it's simply one carless loop that can be fixed with a simple 'select_related'...

Comment: Also a very good solution is @newrelic, it helps you identify bottlenecks in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The here is the free host bit, when on a free host you could be sharing a box with hundreds of other sites (that can equate to a very small amount of ram or CPU). Pay a little money, ($30 dollars / £22 a year) and get your self a better host.

You will find the performance and reliability so much better.

Failing that I would firstly find out what the latency between you and the server is, on a local machine there is no / little network traffic so your pages will appear to load a lot faster.

Next i would look at the actual download speeds you are getting. It could be that your site is limited to 20-30k, which means even a small site will take over a second to load.

Are you hosting many images? If this is the case are you serving them through django or is the webserver doing this. If it is django then make the webserver take this load.

Finally check the processing speed of the pages. Analise the queries which are being run and find out what is taking the time. Make sure that postgres is correctly configured and has enough resources. You can analyses the query speed using the django debug toolbar.