# Django website loads slowely, hosted on apache, using mod_wsgi, any way to make it faster?

Tags: python, django, apache, webserver, mod-wsgi

I have set up a django website on apache on a AWS micro instance. I had a static webpage designed using Twitters bootstrap hosted on /var/www of apache. When I ported that page to django, I find that apache takes longer to serve that page. I am making use of mod_wsgi to host the application and using apache to serve the static files(css, images, etc.). Is there any other way to make the website load faster, or is there any other server that is better suited for Django web applications?

Comment: Has anyone tried hosting python/django apps on servers other than apache?

Comment: Post how you have configured Apache. What MPM, whether using mod_wsgi daemon or worker mode. Likely you are using a configuration which is resulting in Apache having to spin up fresh Apache processes quite frequently, slowing things down. On top of that can be that your application itself is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, anything that requires code to be executed/interpreted is going to be slower than a completely static page.

Some things to think about:

- Do you have a database backend to this page? If so, you should make sure everything is indexed correctly.
- Is there a lot of python code being executed? Are you doing anything that could be optimised?

If you're just rendering the template it is still going to be expensive, since the template has to be run through the Django rendering engine. My advice would be to cache any static assets that you can. A library like this might help: https://github.com/peterbe/django-static

Comment: You could also look into [caching anything expensive to evaluate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache), and making sure you have enough servers running for concurrent access.

Comment: I do have a database in the backend, but I am not pulling any data for this page. as for python code, I am just rendering the template, substituting the STATIC_URL variable.

Answer (score 0):

I answered something similar to this recently check out this stack over flow link

[finding out why a webapp is slow when hosted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938246/finding-out-why-a-webapp-is-slow-when-hosted/9939584#9939584)